# Geometry: Circles Unit

Tags: geometry

Find the length of the chord whose equation is x^2 + y^2 = 57 and is also tangent to the circle whose equation is x^2 + y^2 = 32 and intersects this circle at (4,-4).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming the question should be "find the length of the chord **of the circle** whose equation is...".

This can be done very easily without algebra.  Any tangent to a circle is perpendicular to the radius which meets it, and therefore half of the required chord forms a right-angled triangle together with the radii of the two concentric circles.  (Draw a diagram.)  It therefore has length $\sqrt{57-32}=5$, and the full chord has length $10$.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** the equation of the tangent of the circle
$$
x^2 + y^2 = R^2
$$at the point $(x', y')$ is

$$
xx' + yy' = R^2
$$